# test keeps exciding timeout

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs, supertest

So I have been trying to run a test on my express app using jest and supertest but it keeps exciding the timeout for some reason. I would appreciate it if anyone could help me out here thanks.

**The issue:**
I am writing a test for the */login* path, checking and validating the user input
(phone number and password). the test passed when checking if either of the input is empty but keeps exciding the timeout in a case where the phone number and password match

**Note:** This is working fine on Postman.

below are snippets to give you a better understanding:

**The controller function:**

```js
// login controller using pg
indexController.login = async(req, res) => {
  const {
    phone_number,
    password
  } = req.body
  const client = await pool.connect()
  const response = {
    success: false,
    message: ''
  }
  try {
    if (!phone_number) {
      response.message = 'phone number is required'
      res.status(400).json(response)
    } else if (!password) {
      response.message = 'password is required'
      res.status(400).json(response)
    } else {
      await client.query('BEGIN')
      const result = await client.query('SELECT * FROM ... phone_number = $1 ', [phone_number])
      if (result.rows.length) {
        const hash = result.rows[0].hash
        console.log(result.rows[0])
        const match = //compare hash
        if (match) {
          const userData = await client.query('SELECT * FROM ... id = $1', [result.rows[0].id])
          const token ='user_token'
          await client.query('COMMIT')
          response.success = true
          response.message = 'login successful'
          response.data = userData.rows[0]
          response.token = token
          res.status(200).json(response)
        } else {
          await client.query('COMMIT');
          response.success = false
          response.message = 'Invalid phone number or password'
          res.status(401).json(response);
        }

      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    await client.query('ROLLBACK')
    throw error
  } finally {

    client.release()
  }
}
```

**Test cases:**

```js
describe('POST /login', () => {
    beforeAll(async() => {
      await pool.query(
        'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS register_test (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, phone_number VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL, hash VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL)'
      );
      await pool.query('INSERT INTO register_test (phone_number, hash) VALUES ($1, $2)', [
        '1234567890',
        '$2b$10$fP/nfsJhBpCM8X7VBrTy/uzJ2FVfDKLh/cZ/vR6s/Rs2QjEYsYzkO',
      ]); // phone number: 1234567890, password: password123
    });

    afterAll(async() => {
      await pool.query('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS register_test');
      await pool.end();
    });

    it('should return status 400 if phone number is missing',
      //... passed  
    });

  it('should return status 400 if password is missing',
    //... passed 
  });

it('should return status 200 with token and user data if login is successful', async() => {
  const res = await request(app)
    .post('/login')
    .send({
      phone_number: '1234567890',
      password: 'password123'
    });
  expect(res.status).toBe(200);
  expect(res.body.success).toBe(true);
  expect(res.body.message).toEqual('login successful');
  expect(res.body.data).toHaveProperty('id');
  expect(res.body.data).toHaveProperty('email');
  expect(res.body.data).toHaveProperty('phone_number');
  expect(res.body.token).toBeDefined();
}, 10000); // this keeps exciding the timeout
```